# Loading XML files with different columns into gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, gridview

I have several xml files which I need to load to a Gridview in asp.net. I load one file at a time (depending on the user's choice of file from a dropdownlist), but each xml file has different fields.

E.g.

1. XML1 has ID, Image, City, Location, URL.
2. XML2 has ID, Departure, Destination.
3. XML3 has ID, Image, Description, Destination, Landmark, URL.

I have 2 more xml files, though, actually. But I think these three are sufficient to show the variety of columns I have in the files.

I tried using the AutoGenerateColumns, which was supposed to be most suitable in this condition, except that I now need to show the images in the Gridview.

So basically I need the Gridview to show data with the columns according to the files. One way is by creating a GridView for each XML, but I am wondering if there's another way to solve this. Partially, since I need to unbind the datagrid and remove the viewstate every time the user changes the dropdownlist selection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem but I'm posting the solution I've got so that others can benefit from it.

Here's the link to the solution sample:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13461/how-to-create-columns-dynamically-in-a-grid-view

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to XML to join the XMLs on ID column when user makes selection and bind the gridview with the result. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/03/24/linq-to-xml-join-xml-data.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think that's not what I need. I'm loading one xml file at a time, and there's no need to join the xml files. Those files are independent files.